# (Python 3.8) Is it possible to call a variable or dict by input?

Tags: python, pycharm

Like if I type in something in an input prompt, I want to search my modules for a variable or something to reference, like so:

```py
variable_caller = input().function_here
# or:
variable_caller.function_here
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I cannot understand *call a variable or dict by input*

Comment: Can you elaborate on what your trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [getattr(YOUR_MODULE, variable_selection)](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/getattr)

`getattr()` returns value of `YOUR_MODULE."variable_selection"`.

It gets the value of variable `variable_selection` and converts it into ID.
For example:

```
a = "attribute"
getattr(module, a) # Returns module.attribute
```